# Can you say HaShem's name in personal tefillot?

Tags: tefilla

When saying a personal tefilla at the end of shemoneh esrei, and one is saying "May it be Your will, HaShem, etc." is it proper to say HaShem's actual name or not to?

Comment: Why wouldn't you?

Comment: The possibility of saying HaShem's name when you're not supposed to, or in vain.